# NSMutable Array won't alloc, remains nil

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, alloc

A XML parser is trying to alloc its delegate's NSMutable array called **masterCodeList**. From the following code, you'll see that this fails. (I am a total newbie.)

```
if (dataController.masterCodeList == nil){

    dataController.masterCodeList =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (dataController.masterCodeList == nil) {
        NSLog(@"the init of the mutable array did NOT work");
    }
}
```

I get the `the init of the mutable array did NOT work` message every time. I am importing the dataController header.

```
#import "CodeDataController.h"
```

I am getting no other error message, the parser is parsing fine and the app is running smoothly without content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using ARC?  how is "`masterCodeList`" defined in your dataController object?

Comment: is dataController nill?

Comment: Also, why do you have your lower level (child) XML parser attempting to allocate your delegate's (potentially parent's "masterCodeList".  Why is the delegate not doing this itself?

Comment: I declare CodeDataController *dataController in the interface for the parser. Is that enough?

Comment: dataController IS null! What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

What does your declaration of masterCodeList look like?
Is it a property, and is it synthesized, or are you making your own setter/getter?

An alternative would be to try using an intermediate placeholder, ie:

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[dataController setMasterCodeList:temp];
```

and see if that sets your array correctly.

(note: that code may or may not have leaks)

Comment: It is a property:
 property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *masterCodeList;

and it is synthesized:
 synthesize masterCodeList=_masterCodeList;

I've tried a temp array before and it did not work (I'll try it again). I've also tried this and it didn't work:
[dataController setMasterCodeList:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];

Answer (score 0):

could you post your implementation of the dataController object in this class, and its attributes from the other class?

you also may want to try using the isEqual method instead of == nil.

Comment: if it's a pointer, what does using the isEqual method do for you? == should be just fine. Of course, if you really want to be a legit C-style programmer you do if(!dataController.masterCodeList)